Custom Matrix Product in NumPy with User-Defined Element-Wise Operations
I am looking for a way to perform a custom matrix product in NumPy where I can replace the element-wise multiplication and addition operations with self-defined functions, such as lambda expressions. Specifically, I want to maintain the matrix multiplication signature (n,k),(k,m) -> (n,m), but use custom operators for the scalar multiplication and addition within the matrix product computation.
Example:
Given two matrices A and B:
A = [[a_11, a_12],
     [a_21, a_22]]

B = [[b_11, b_12],
     [b_21, b_22]]

The standard matrix product C = AB is calculated as:
C_ij = sum(A_ix * B_xj for x in range(k))

I want to replace the multiplication (*) and addition (sum) operations with custom functions, e.g., custom_multiply and custom_add, such that:
C_ij = custom_add(custom_multiply(A_i1, B_1j), custom_multiply(A_i2, B_2j), ..., custom_multiply(A_ik, B_kj))

Custom Operators:
For instance, I might want to define:
custom_multiply = lambda x, y: (x&0xff) * y  # Custom multiplication function
custom_add = lambda x, y: max(x, y)          # Custom addition function

Use Case:
I believe it is useful to have a custom matrix product for various applications. For example, in networking, the computation of routes can follow the general process of matrix multiplication when the adjacency matrix is given. However, the element-wise operations must be customized to conform to specific restrictions required by certain routing protocols.
Question:
I do not want to use plain loops to fulfill matrix product. My custom element-wise operations can be decomposed into a series of basic arithmetic operations that are supported by NumPy and can be extended/broadcast to matrix-wise. I'd like to know:

Is there a built-in NumPy function to support custom matrix products?
If not, is there a general way to break down the matrix product process into a series of matrix-wise operations in an efficient way?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Matrix multiplication can done with an appropriately broadcasted elementwise multiplication followed by sum on one of the dimensions.  You can see this in the einsum notation, 'ij,jk->ik' (sum on the j dimension).

Shouldn't sum(A_ik * B_kj for k in range(n)) rather be sum(A_ix * B_xj for x in range(k))?

matmul is particularly fast because it uses, where possible, optimized BLAS code.  If you use dtypes that can't use that code, the multiplication will be much slower.  But as long as your custom functions use regular numpy operators/ufunc, your version should have speeds similar to the broadcasted 'multiply'/sum equivalent.

apl a computer language the preceeded MATLAB and numpy by many years, wrote the inner (matrix) product as A+.×B, denoting times followed by the reduction sum.  The two operators could be replaced by other ones, such as logicals and min/max ones.

@hpaulj Thanks. Very helpful information. I'm aware that the main benefits could be efficient broadcasting and more in a coding aspect. Also thanks for informing apl.

I am not aware of a readily available way to provide your own reduction and element-wise multiplication to the matrix product in Numpy. However, you could write your own function that achieves the same:
def my_matmul(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply):
    tmp = my_multiply(a[..., None], b[None, ...])  # n×k(×1) ∘ (1×)k×m → n×k×m
    return my_sum(tmp)  # n×k×m → n×m

Here, my_sum is the custom reduction function in place of the matrix product's sum, and my_multiply is the custom element-wise function in place of the matrix product's multiplication.
In the given form, my_sum and my_multiply have to fulfill the following criteria:

my_sum always has to reduce along axis 1,
my_multiply has to adhere to the standard Numpy broadcasting rules.

For example, we could use:

my_sum = lambda array: np.max(array, axis=1) (Maximum instead of summation)
my_multiply = lambda a, b: (a + 1) / (b - 1) (add 1 to elements in a, subtract 1 from elements in b, then divide instead of multiply)

Here is a full example, including test cases:
import numpy as np
rand = np.random.default_rng(42)

a, b = rand.normal(size=(3, 4)), rand.normal(size=(4, 3))

def my_matmul(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply):  # Proposed vectorized implementation
    tmp = my_multiply(a[..., None], b[None, ...])  # n×k(×1) ∘ (1×)k×m → n×k×m
    return my_sum(tmp)  # n×k×m → n×m

def my_matmul_loop(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply): # Explicit loopy implementation
    n_rows, n_cols = a.shape[0], b.shape[1]
    c = np.empty((n_rows, n_cols), dtype=float)
    for row in range(n_rows):
        for col in range(n_cols):
            tmp = my_multiply(a[row, :], b[:, col])
            # k → 1×k, as `my_sum` reduces axis 1; `squeeze()` for scalar result
            c[row, col] = my_sum(tmp[None, ...]).squeeze()
    return c

# Do standard sum and standard multiplication result in standard matrix product?
my_sum = lambda array: np.sum(array, axis=1)
my_multiply = np.multiply
assert np.allclose(a @ b, my_matmul_loop(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply))
assert np.allclose(a @ b, my_matmul(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply))

# Same result for loopy and vectorized version with custom sum and product?
my_sum = lambda array: np.max(array, axis=1)
my_multiply = lambda a, b: (a + 1) / (b - 1)
assert np.allclose(my_matmul_loop(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply),
                   my_matmul(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply))

Finally, to make sure that the given functions my_sum and my_multiply indeed behave as expected, we could add some sanity checks on the intermediate shapes:
def my_matmul(a, b, my_sum, my_multiply):  # Proposed vectorized implementation
    assert a.shape[1] == b.shape[0]
    tmp = my_multiply(a[..., None], b[None, ...])  # n×k(×1) ∘ (1×)k×m → n×k×m
    assert tmp.shape == (a.shape[0], a.shape[1], b.shape[1])
    tmp = my_sum(tmp)  # n×k×m → n×m
    assert tmp.shape == (a.shape[0], b.shape[1])
    return tmp


Thanks! This is by far the most elegant and efficient implementation, I assume.

I notice that the intermediate step would introduce size inflation, \ie n×k(×1) ∘ (1×)k×m → n×k×m. Is this avoidable? For example, is it possible to delay this step so that it can be combined with the my_sum and reduced in place?

@PorcupineAndrew Indeed, that might be an issue, depending on the size of your data. I don't think there is an easy solution for this, as it is a principle problem with the custom matrix product, when you want to supply custom multiplication and reduction: you first have to produce the result for reduction (which implies inflation), before you can reduce. I don't think there is a "one-fits-all" solution, but probably multiple ways to go: (1) given a specific formulation, you could write your own code that fuses multiplication and reduction in one step, depending on the actual problem …

… but this would not give you a general solution where you can pass arbitrary multiplication and reduction functions. (2) Rather than multiply-reduce the full array at once, you can introduce partial loops (over the rows or columns, e.g.), which would imply partial inflation only and would thus be a time-memory tradeoff. (3) You could use a fully looped solution (i.e. element-wise result calculation) and use a library such as numba (https://numba.pydata.org/) for speedup. This could be a good compromise of enabling custom solutions and maintaining speed, at the expense of adding a dependency.

Thanks for suggestions. Yeah, I have tried plain loops with numba and also partial loops. The latter seems better in my case. Anyway, your answer has cleared my questions. Thx

I, for whatever that's worth, am not aware of a numpy built-in that achieves what you want.
As to how that can be achieved, in a somewhat efficient manner, the comments already gave some hints, but here's a fleshed out version.
from typing import Callable

import numpy as np


def munge(A: np.ndarray, B: np.ndarray, mult: Callable, sum_: Callable) -> np.ndarray:
    n, m = A.shape
    m_, k = B.shape
    assert m == m_

    return np.array([[sum_(mult(A[i, :], B[:, j])) for j in range(k)] for i in range(n)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = np.random.randn(3, 4)
    B = np.random.randn(4, 5)

    C = A @ B
    C_ = munge(A, B, np.multiply, np.sum)

    print(np.all(np.isclose(C, C_)))

This broadcasts over the shared dimension, but iterates over the (possibly) distinct ones, so it will likely not be as efficient as the standard matmul operation. I don't see an easy way to fix that. It does however use efficient broadcasting where possible.

You can define your own subtype of int
class MyNum(int):

    def __mul__(self, b):
        return MyNum((self&0xff)*b)

    def __add__(self, b):
        return MyNum(max(self, b))

And then use it to create a numpy array of those
M=[np.array([[MyNum(i+3*j) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)], dtype=object)

Then, some basic numpy operations would work with your new type definition of + and *
for example
M@M

is
array([[243, 252, 261, 270, 279, 288, 297, 306, 315, 324],
       [324, 336, 348, 360, 372, 384, 396, 408, 420, 432],
       [405, 420, 435, 450, 465, 480, 495, 510, 525, 540],
       [486, 504, 522, 540, 558, 576, 594, 612, 630, 648],
       [567, 588, 609, 630, 651, 672, 693, 714, 735, 756],
       [648, 672, 696, 720, 744, 768, 792, 816, 840, 864],
       [729, 756, 783, 810, 837, 864, 891, 918, 945, 972],
       [810, 840, 870, 900, 930, 960, 990, 1020, 1050, 1080],
       [891, 924, 957, 990, 1023, 1056, 1089, 1122, 1155, 1188],
       [972, 1008, 1044, 1080, 1116, 1152, 1188, 1224, 1260, 1296]],
      dtype=object)

But it must be noted that this is not better than defining ad-hoc pure python functions. Numpy role is to perform well on "strides/shape" contiguous array of numbers (that what the "num" stands for, after all); in which case it relies on heavily optimized cblas/lapack. But if you try to use it to perform pure python code (using this trick, or using any function that use a lambda as parameter, such as vectorize, apply_along_axis, etc, then, it becomes just an alternative way to run pure (therefore very slow) python code.
So, it is just for the sake of noting custom matrix multiplication @, but it wouldn't be "numpy vectorized", and any faster than the most naive custom_add, custom_mul, custom_matmul implementation, or faster than the other answers you already got.
